Number of factors of a number can at most be?
Given any $n$, can one determine the maximum number of factors that $n$ can have? I couldn't determine much mathematically, so I tried computing the result and I obtained this

The graph seems to be exponentially decaying, does there exist any closed form or inequality that relates number of factors of $n$ and $n$?
(PS : I need the upper bound for increasing the computational efficiency of a different related problem)

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3043181/42969

Ohk, thanks......

Please clarify "number of factors" , do you count the divisors or only the prime factors , exclude or include the nontrivial factors etc.

Divisors........

Lots of information at the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate

Dissertation of G. Robin: With equality at $n = 6983776800 $ and $d(n) = 2304,$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1.5379398606751... \right)} =  n^{ \left( \frac{1.0660186782977...}{\log \log n} \right) }. $$
With equality at a number $n$ near $6.929 \cdot 10^{40},$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1.934850967971...}{\log \log n} \right)}.   $$ Compare this one with Theorem 317 in Hardy and Wright, attributed to Wigert (1907),
$$ \limsup \frac{\log d(n)  \log \log n}{\log n} = \log 2.  $$
